# Add String[] array to another String[] array

Tags: java, arrays, string

One of my method returns String[] array in a loop. While loop contiues, I want to add these String[] arrays to another String[] array. I want something like this given below. It gives ype mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String error.

```
String[] searchResultList = new String[25];
int count = 0;
for (...) {
          String[] resultList = getArray(parameter);
          searchResultList[count] = resultList;
          count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Well you've tried setting an *element* of a string array to be another string array. You can't do that.

Either you need to make your `searchResultList` an *array* of string arrays (`String[][]`) or you need to copy all the strings *within* `resultList` into `searchResultList`.

Whichever way you choose, you should probably consider using a `List<String>` instead of arrays... that way you don't need to hard code some arbitrary upper limit to the array size, as a list can grow.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to store a `String[]` - i.e. a String array, a number of Strings - in an array that stores `String` - i.e. just single Strings.  You can put one bag inside another bag directly, you need to take the things out of the bag first.

So what you need to do is:

1. Add the entries in the returned `resultList` array one by one to the `searchResultList` array
2. And make sure you alter the size of the `searchResultList` array to hold all the new values

Or, a much better solution you could just [use a `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) since they grow automatically and allow you to add multiple items at once:

```
List<String> searchResultList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (...) {
    String[] resultList = getArray(parameter);
    searchResultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(resultList));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `searchResultList` variable stores `String` elements but you try and add a `String[]` to it, so this is normal.

Why don't you make `searchResultList` an `ArrayList<String>`, and also `getArray()` return such an ArrayList as well? This way, all you'd have to do is `searchResultList.add(getArray(parameter));`

Comment: I am not using List because of requirements.

Comment: You do know that List<> has a `.toArray()` operation, don't you?

Comment: @imrantariq - you can use a List *despite* of the requirements.  Think about it ...

Answer (score 0):

U should use  ArrayUtils.addAll(..) to add all elements from one array to another.

Comment: this solution rely on org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils doing all the dirty work

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a requirement to use String[] rather than List. But nothing should stop you from using List internally in your method and returning an array, e.g.

```
    List<String> searchResult = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (?) {
        String[] resultList = getArray(parameter);
        searchResult.addAll(Arrays.asList(resultList));
    }
    return searchResult.toArray(new String[searchResult.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] resultList = getArray(parameter);
searchResultList[count] = resultList;
```

Here, resultList is array..
But searchResultList[count] is String..
So you r getting "cannot convert from String[] to String error."
better u can use

```
String[] resultList = getArray(parameter);
searchResultList[count] = resultList[count];
```

..
use this.Now you can get with statement

Answer (score 0):

```
Add String[] array to another String[] array


  public static String[] addAll(String[] array1, String... array2) {
            if (array1 == null) {
                return array2;
            } else if (array2 == null) {
                return array1;
            } else {
                String[] joinedArray = new String[array1.length + array2.length];
                System.arraycopy(array1, 0, joinedArray, 0, array1.length);
                System.arraycopy(array2, 0, joinedArray, array1.length, array2.length);
                return joinedArray;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57247918/edit) your answer to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Here is result . For add one String array to another String

Comment: @MebinJoe [mre]s are really for questions, not answers. I think the answer could do with a little explanation (possibly of how it's different to the existing answers) but it really isn't an answerer's responsibility to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an existing array of string to another array I use :

```
 private ArrayList<String> concatArray(ArrayList<String> TabEvenHis) {
        ArrayList<String> TabFin = new ArrayList<String>();
        String sEven; 
        for (int i = 0; i < TabEvenHis.size(); i++) {
            sEven = TabEvenHis.get(i);
            TabFin.add(sEven);
        }
        return TabFin;
    }
```

*Call :*

```
MyArrayExisting=concatArray(ArrayToAdd);
```